# subsetting a data frame by partially matching another data frame in r (open to python/pandas solution)

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, subset

**basic problem description :**

Let `df` be a data frame and `df_match` a one row data frame.

I want to subset `df` such that only the rows remain whose non NA-Values are contained in the non-NA values of `df_match`.

**A minimal example :**

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("a1", "a1", "a2", NA, "a1", "a1"), 
             B = c(NA,"b1", "b1", "b2", "b1",NA), 
             C = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"c1","c1"),
             D = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"d1","d1"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# column D is not nessecary I imputed it to get a data frame when applying is.na() below

df_match <- data.frame(A= "a1", 
                       B = "b1", 
                       C = NA,
                       D = NA,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


     A    B    C    D
1   a1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
2   a1   b1 <NA> <NA>
3   a2   b1 <NA> <NA>
4 <NA>   b2 <NA> <NA>
5   a1   b1   c1   d1
6   a1 <NA>   c1   d1

> df_match
   A  B  C  D
1 a1 b1 NA NA
```

In the minimal example only the first two rows of `df` are correct w.r.t. "the partial matching".

```
   A    B  C  D
1 a1 <NA> NA NA
2 a1   b1 NA NA
```

The 3rd and 4th row has a wrong entry either in column A or column B.

The 5th and 6th contain a value in a column which is not supported in `df_match` (i.e. the columns which have non NA values in df_match).

```
     A    B    C    D
1   a2   b1 <NA> <NA>
2 <NA>   b2 <NA> <NA>
3   a1   b1   c1   d1
4   a1 <NA>   c1   d1
```

**Basic idea :**

was to match each row of `df` with `df_match` and store the result in a boolean matrix `M`.

Then create a boolean vector indexed by the row number as follows : TRUE if

1) the columns of `M` which have support on `df_match` ( i.e. the columns which have non-NA values in df_match) contain no false.

2) the columns of `M` which do not have support in `df_match` contain no TRUE

**My current solution to the minimal example :**

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("a1", "a1", "a2", NA, "a1", "a1"), 
             B = c(NA,"b1", "b1", "b2", "b1",NA), 
             C = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"c1","c1"),
             D = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"d1","d1"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# column D is not nessecary I imputed it to get a data frame when applying is.na() below

df_match <- data.frame(A= "a1", 
                       B = "b1", 
                       C = NA,
                       D = NA,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(dplyr)

# create a boolean vector for condition 2
not_matchable <- names(df_match)[is.na(df_match)]
bol_no_matchable <- df %>%
      select(one_of(not_matchable)) %>%
      is.na() %>%
      apply(X = ., MARGIN = 1, any)

# create a boolean vector for condition 1
matchable <- names(df_match)[!is.na(df_match)]
bol_matchable <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(row)
    {
    df[row,matchable] != df_match[,matchable]
  }) %>%
    apply(X = ., MARGIN = 2, FUN = any)

bol_matchable[is.na(bol_matchable)] <- FALSE 

# filter the results
df <- df %>%
   filter(!bol_matchable & bol_no_matchable)
```

**Questions :**

- What general principles I can follow to rise the performance of subsetting problems?
- How can I improve the perfomance of the above code?
- How can I improve the perfomance of the below code concerning my real problem?

**Problem:** 
In the application the data frame `df` has a column `X` containing a column name where `df` is allowed to have values outside the support of `df_match`. (see below)

Applying the logic from the basic minimal example my current solution is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("a1", "a1", "a2", NA, "a1", "a1"), 
                 B = c(NA,"b1", "b1", "b2", "b1",NA), 
                 C = c("c2",NA,"c1",NA,"c1","c1"),
                 D = c(NA,"d2","d2","d2","d1","d1"),
                 X = c("C","D","C","D","D","C"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

bol <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x)
{
  # determine value in column X
  X <- pull(df[x,], "X")
  not_matchable <- setdiff(matchable, X)
  # create boolean vector for condition 1)
  bol_no_matchable <- df[x,] %>%
    select(one_of(not_matchable)) %>%
    is.na() %>%
    all()

  # create boolean vector for condition 2)
  bol_matchable <- {df[x,not_matchable] != df_match[,not_matchable]} 
  bol_matchable[is.na(bol_matchable)] <- FALSE
  bol_matchable <- any(bol_matchable)

  # combine both conditions
  bol <- !bol_matchable & bol_no_matchable
})
```

The above code is not as fast as I like to have it. As I want to apply this "function" to a dataframe `df` with ~50m rows and 100+ columns multiple times for arbitary data frames `df_match`.

Hence any suggestions/ ideas for different approaches are welcome as well as comments towards subsetting.

Comment: As far I see, this is an `R` code. Why do you tag `python` and `pandas`? If you are open to python/pandas solution, you should have said so in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I changed the title. 
python/ pandas was a suggestion from this forum which I addepted without questioning it due to lack of experience here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Map` over the columns of `df` and `df_match`, and for each column-pair return a vector whose elements are `TRUE` if the corresponding element of `df` is `NA` or equals the element of `df_match`. Then select the rows where the number of `TRUE`s (yielded by `rowSums`) is equal to the number of columns (i.e. all columns either match or are NA).

Note: If the `df_match` value is `NA` and the `df` value is non-`NA`, the corresponding vector element output by `Map` will be `NA`, which is equivaluent to `FALSE` when using `rowSums` with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
row_matches <- 
  rowSums(mapply(function(x, y)  is.na(x) | x == y, df, df_match),  na.rm = TRUE)

df[row_matches == ncol(df),]
#    A    B    C    D
# 1 a1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2 a1   b1 <NA> <NA>
```